# List of countries and their states in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Where is the list of countries and states located in wordpress?
When you select United States on a checkout form the "state" field immediately changes to contain the list of states. I would like to imitate this behavior for other countries. For example when selecting Honduras, you will get the list of states of that country.

**Is there an XML file, php file or Database table where Wordpress access this information?** that way it could be editable to be able to add the states without having to add a plugin or write extra code.

I know you can access the list from the code with `WC()->countries->get_states` how ever where is it obtaining it from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a folder called `i18n` and in that folder there is another folder called `states`, which contains a list of files. Add your file there as `HN.php` with a list of the states you want shown e.g.:

```
<?php
/**
 * Honduras
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @category    i18n
 * @package     WooCommerce/i18n
 * @version     2.0.0
 */
global $states;

$states['HN'] = array(
'AA' => __( 'Some state', 'woocommerce' ),
);
```